Bottom Tab Bar is pushed upward when the keyboard opens
The solution provided in this thread is applicablle to all the screens but I need to implement it only on some specific screen how  to do this ?
I tried below things but they are impact all the screens
screenOptions={{
          tabBarHideOnKeyboard: true,
      }}

<application
      <activity
        
         <!-- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" Added this -->       
        
      </activity>
     
    </application>


Have you tried storing style in state, and then updating the state when the keyboard shows/dismisses? https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.74/keyboard#addlistener

You can style the tabBar using the screenOptions prop https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#tabbarstyle

This can be resolved by wraping the Screen Content that is showing the keyboard, with KeyboardAvoidingView as shown in below example:
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

function MyScreen() {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
    >
      <ScrollView>
        {/* Screen content goes here */}
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}

Keep in mind to use the behaviour property as it is shown in the example.
